# Model with the same property name throws error: has properties that are declared multiple times in its class hierarchy

Tags: realm

I have a project that displays two types of document, one from local storage and another from dropbox, so i have two Model, XXDocument and DBDocument.  Both model have properties such as name, extension and last updated.  I assume it's a common scenario, but on start realm throws and error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object 'DBDocument' has properties that are declared multiple times in its class hierarchy: 'name', 'lastUpdated', 'extension''

What's the right way to handle this?  Do i prefix each property with Model name?

Edit

Just to clear a few things.  I've tried to use a super class to hold the common field and also use two separated class without super class, both case does not work.

Case 1:
XXDocument
- name
- extension
- lastUpdated

DBDocument
- name
- extension
- lastUpdated
- rev
- filepath

Case 2:

Case 1:

BaseDocument
- name
- extension
- lastUpdated

XXDocument -> BaseDocument // XXDocument class has no properties now

DBDocument -> BaseDocument
- rev
- filepath

Answer (score 2):

If you have declared the properties in a superclass of `DBDocument`, you shouldn't be declaring them again in `DBDocument`, since Realm walks the class hierarchy of your classes to collect the set of properties for the model class.

Comment: I started with two separated classes, DBDocument, XXDocument and later I've tried to use a BaseDocument which holds common properties and have DBDocument and XXDocument extend BaseDocument.  Both cases causes crash

Comment: That's fine to extend the base class, just make sure you're not redeclaring the properties from the base class in the subclass.